# emit to a specific socket (socket.io v2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i am trying to emit to a specific socket and tried almost everything but no luck.

two connections

client1 - side clientside

```
var socket = io.connect('/room2');
socket.on('msg', function(msg) {
 console.log(msg);
 }
```

client2 - side ejs

```
var socket = io.connect('/room1');
socket.emit('message', 'This is my message');
```

client2 - server side

```
socket.on('messsage', function(msg) {
   var clinet1 = io.to(socket.id of client 1).emit('msg', "send message');
    //Not working

   var client1 = io.of('/room1').to('client1').emit('msg', 'send message');
    //Not working

   io.sockets.connected[socket_id].emit('msg', 'send message');
   // not working

}
```

Comment: There's not enough detail here.  Your mixing both namespaces and rooms, but don't show us enough code to know if you're doing that correctly or if you have them confused.  In any case `io.of('/room1').to('client1')` looks wrong.  We'd have to know what you were expecting that to do in order to know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `'message'` to any other name. The event name `'message'` is reserved and is only send by `socket.send`